# Proof of reduceness in M. Greenberg's Rational Points in Henselian Discerete Valuation Rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, schemes

This question concerns a Marvin Greenberg's paper
on Rational Points in Henselian Discerete Valuation Rings ([springer link](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02684802)) and
part of the main's theorem proof on page 62.

Let $(R,m,k)$ be a Henselian DVR and $Y$ be an affine,
*non-separable* scheme over $R$
defined by the polynomial system $I$
($Y= \operatorname{Spec} R[X_1,...X_n]/I \cdot R[X_1,...X_n]))$. Let $K'$ be a purely inseparable finite extension of field
of fractions $K:= Q(R)$ such that the scheme $Y_{K'}$ is not reduced, then a fortiori  $Y_{K'}$  is not reduced.
(By [EGA IV; 4.6-3] such inseparable $K'$ always exists).

It uses the *Fact 2* that There is a functor $\mathcal{F}$
from the category of affine schemes of finite type over $R'$
to affine schemes of finite type over $R$ such that
$\mathcal{F}$ is right adjoint to the change of base functor
from $R$ to $R'$.
Thus we have an isomorphism of bifunctors

$$ \operatorname{Mor}_R(Y, \mathcal{F}Z) \to 
\operatorname{Mor}_{R'}(Y_{R'}, Z)  $$

for $Y/R, Z/R'$. Moreover, $\mathcal{F}$  preserves closed
immersions. [Technique de descent, II, Seminaire Bourbaki; p. 195-13]
Now we can consider the part of the original proof:

> Consider the affine scheme $\mathcal{F}Y_{R'}$ over $R$.
> There is a canonical $R$-morphism $\theta: Y \to 
> \mathcal{F}Y_{R'}$ which corresponds by adjointness to
> the identity morphism of $Y_{R'}$. By Fact 2,
> $\mathcal{F}((Y_{R'})_{red})$ is a closed subscheme of
> $\mathcal{F}Y_{R'}$; let $W:=
> \theta^{-1}(\mathcal{F}((Y_{R'})_{red}))$ be its pre-image
> under $\theta$.

> The claim is that then $W$ is a *proper* closed subcheme of $Y$,
> otherwise the identity morphism of $Y_{R'}$, would
> factor through $(Y_{R'})_{red}$, i.e.,
> $Y_{R'}$ would be reduced, contradicting the choice of $R'$.

The last argument is hard to understand. I'm going to assure that
$W \neq Y$ and assume for now that $W= Y$ and pursue to get a contradiction.

The composition $W = \theta^{-1}(\mathcal{F}((Y_{R'})_{red}))
\to \mathcal{F}((Y_{R'})_{red}) \to \mathcal{F}((Y_{R'})$
coinsides after identification $W= Y$ with
$\theta: Y \to \mathcal{F}Y_{R'}$ and since
the isomorphism of bifunctors in Fact 2 is functorial
I get a factorization of identity morphism of $Y_{R'}$
by $Y_{R'} \to (Y_{R'})_{red} \to Y_{R'}$ where the right
arrow is the canonical closed embedding.

Why this implies that $Y_{R'} = (Y_{R'})_{red} $, i.e.,
that $Y_{R'}$ is reduced? Don't we need also to assure that the identity of $ (Y_{R'})_{red}$
factorizes with same morphisms as
$ (Y_{R'})_{red} \to  (Y_{R'}) \to  (Y_{R'})_{red}$ to complete the proof?

Comment: There is much I don't 'own' here, so I hesitate to comment: but aren't you in the situation of $B \to B/J \to B$ being the identity implies that $J= 0$?  (where, here, $Y_{R'}= \mathop{\text{Spec}} B$, and $J$ ideal of $B$, defining the reduced subscheme.)

Comment: @peterag: 
I think you touched exactly the right point but 
I don't think that it's is obvious here that $B \to B/J \to B$
beeing identity implies $J=0$. Take as example
$B= K[X_1, X_2,... ]$, with $K$ arbitr field, $J := (X_1)$ and
consider two $K$-morphisms $f_1: B \to B/J, X_i \mapsto X_{i+1}$ 
and $f_2: B/J \to B, X_{j+1} \mapsto X_j$. Observe that 
$B/J = K[X_2,X_3,...]$ and the composition $f_2 \circ f_1$ is
identity on $B$.

Comment: Well, I have to confess that I was a bit cheatting here sice in the
question we assumed the rings/schemes to be of 
finite type, so that's a "fake" conterexample. But nevertheless
one could ask if $B$ is a finitely generated $A$ algebra over 
ring $A$, $J$ an ideal of $B$ and two arbitrary $A$-module 
morphisms $g_1: B \to B/J, g_2: B/J \to B$ compose to identity
$id_B = g_2 \circ g_1$, is $J=0$? Do you see an argument why
this should be true?

Comment: Quite apart from your second comment, I don't think your counter-example is applicable here, because the map $B\to B/J$ is the quotient map: $J$ is the kernel, as $J$ defines the closed subscheme: in the case at hand $J = \mathop{\text{nilrad}} B= \sqrt 0$. In any event, that is what I was thinking (the 'because' of this comment).

Comment: Yes, that's what I have overlooked, that the involved 
$(Y_{R'})_{red} \to  (Y_{R'})$ corresponded to the 
canonical closed embedding resp the related ring map to
'canonical' quotient $B \to B/J$. Then I understand your 
argument.

Comment: A nitpick: do you know if it's also true that if
$B$ is finitely generated $R$ algebra and 
$g_1: B \to B/J, g_2: B/J \to B$ are arbitrary(!) ring maps
which respect $A$-algebra structure  (i.e. additionally
$A$-module morphisms) with additional property that
$id_B = g_2 \circ g_1$ holds, does it imply that $J=0$ 
is also zero in that case? The interesting point is 
if we can also deduce that $J=0$ if we NOT assume that $g_1$ 
to be the canonical quotient map.

Comment: I do not  know - but I bet one and a half penny that someone on this site does. If you're interested you could ask - be sure to include your counter-example so that, in the lyrical words of the up/down vote arrows, the question 'shows research effort; it is useful and clear'

Comment: Yes, it works: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4005122/composition-b-to-b-j-to-b-equals-identity-implies-that-the-ideal-j-is-zero/4005173?noredirect=1#comment8267409_4005173 !

Comment: Thanks - I will look at it.